Determining geometric nature of $Z(t)$ nontrivial zeros plots of even/odd Analytic rank elliptic curves
Questions arising from my recent email excerpt (reproduced) to LMFDB Support but I was given unsatisfactory answers:
In LMFDB website, I could not determine from the individual {elliptic curve page / its associated L-function page / Downloads} the specific information I am seeking regarding $Z(t)$ plots of nontrivial zeros for various Analytic rank elliptic curves.
The sign (root number) of functional equation $= \epsilon = +1$ [for even Analytic rank elliptic curves "with Line symmetry"] or $-1$ [for odd Analytic rank elliptic curves "with Point symmetry"].
$Z(t)$ plots will "meaninglessly" oscillate infinitely many times above and below the horizontal axis $t$. But $Z(t)$ plots do "geometrically" display in the $\{0 < t < \infty \text{ range}\}$ the "first sinusoidal wave" that could be determined by arbitrarily choosing
$\epsilon^{1/2}=\pm1$(for "CASE" even Analytic rank) and $\epsilon^1/2 = \pm i$(for "CASE" odd Analytic rank). In either "CASE", we make a choice, but we accept that the chosen choice is arbitrary and OVERALL NOT mathematically meaningful.
I came up with the following observational concepts. Analytic rank r of elliptic curves $E$
consist of:
(1) even $r = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10... $[with $\epsilon = 1, \epsilon^{1/2}= \pm1$that can arbitrarily be chosen or assigned to display $Z(t)$ plots in two reciprocal manners "$+1 Z(t)$" or "$-1 Z(t)$"], and
(2) odd $r = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9... $[with $\epsilon = -1, \epsilon^{1/2}=\pm i$that can arbitrarily be chosen or assigned to display $Z(t)$ plots in two reciprocal manners "$+i Z(t)$" or "$-i Z(t)$"].
All available LMFDB $Z(t)$ graphs for even Analytic rank elliptic curves [of $r = 0, 2,$ "solitary" $4$] are displayed as if we made the "standardized" choice of $\epsilon^{1/2} = +1$; viz "$+1 Z(t)$". For if [some of] the choice we made had been $epsilon^{1/2} = -1$, then I think
some of the $Z(t)$ plots will be displayed in a reciprocal manner "upside down" reflected by horizontal axis $t$ as "$-1 Z(t)$".
All available LMFDB $Z(t)$ graphs for odd Analytic rank elliptic curves [of 1 and 3] are displayed as if choice of $\epsilon^{1/2} = +i$; viz "$+i Z(t)$" was made for Analytic rank $1$. BUT $\epsilon^1/2 = -i$; viz "$-i Z(t)$" was made for Analytic rank $3$ OR vice versa OR the choice of $\epsilon^{1/2}$ was "standardized" BUT Analytic rank $1$, then $3$, then $5$, then $7\cdots$ will [intrinsically] display "first sinusoidal wave" in an alternating manner.
My big question is whether $Z(t)$ plots in LMFDB website for Analytic $1$ versus Analytic $3$ elliptic curves had or had not (somehow) utilize different choice of $\epsilon^{1/2} = +i$ OR $\epsilon^1/2 = -i$. Then seeing the "geometrical character" of any future Z(t) plots for (odd) Analytic rank $5$ elliptic, etc would also be interesting.

I think in the explanation for the $Z$-function in the LMFDB it does say that the sign of $\varepsilon^{1/2}$ is chosen so that $Z(t)$ is positive when $t$ is small. Choosing the other square root would just reflect the graphs in the horizontal axis. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question though...

From Joseph Harrison's useful vewpoint, let us say the chosen sign is STANDARDIZED by LMFDB as: +1 (for even Analytic rank 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10... elliptic curves) and +i (for odd Analytic rank 1, 3, 5, 7, 9... elliptic curves) """"so that Z(t) is positive when t is small"""". Then the "first sinusoidal wave" OPPOSITE/DIFFERENT manifestation on (available) Z(t) plots for Analytic rank 1 versus Analytic rank 3 is a novel intrinsic phenomenon. Can we predict what Z(t) plots for Analytic rank 5 would look like? Kind regards, John Ting

Your comment does not make sense. Either you enforce $\epsilon=1$ or $\epsilon=i$ depending on the parity of the analytic rank (let’s call it the uniform normalization), or you choose epsilon so that $Z(t)>0$ for small $t>0$ (the “LMFDB normalization”). You really need to be more precise about this “first sinusoidal wave opposite/different manifestation” that you write about. It’s hard to understand what you mean beyond guesses. Do you mean that, in the uniform normalization, the sign of $Z(t)$ (in a neighborhood of $0$ in $[0,\infty)$) is not the same in analytic rank $1$ as in rank $3$?

In term of "uniform normalization" (by Aphelli): Biggest question is whether "uniform normalization" was actually carried out for LMFDB elliptic curves with rank 1 vs rank 3. Now, one can do Z(t) plots WITHOUT square root being applied to sign epsilon [giving UNIFORM choice of 1 (for even rank) and i (for odd rank)] but LMFDB use Z(t) plots WITH square root being applied to sign epsilon. sqrt (1) = +/- 1 (relevant to even rank) and sqrt (-1) = +/- i (relevant to odd rank). Then LMFDB should "uniformly" use (say) +i for BOTH rank 1 and 3. The "first sinusoidal wave" is a "feature" of Z(t) plot.

“A feature” could refer to anything and does not enlighten us at all about what exactly interests you in this “first sinusoidal wave” (which is not even sinusoidal!)… anyway, assuming the relevant Riemann Hypothesis for this $L$-function, you can show that the root of unity in the LMFDB normalization is always exactly $i^{-r}$, where $r$ is the analytic rank. So to go between the LMFDB normalization and the uniform normalization, you have to change signs exactly when $r \equiv 1,2 \pmod{4}$.

Randomly chosen Rank 1 https://www.lmfdb.org/L/2/82/1.1/c1/0/2 VERSUS Randomly chosen Rank 3 https://www.lmfdb.org/L/2/21858/1.1/c1/0/3 . We immediately see [RESPECTIVELY] "first sinusoidal wave" starting in "+ve" 1st Quadrant versus "-ve" 4th Quadrant. This phenomenon is GENERALIZED and, assuming LMFDB UNIFORMLY choose (say) +i for both rank 1 and rank 3; then this is useful "feature". Can anyone predict what Z(t) plot for an rank 5 elliptic curve may look like (once one is available)?

Please do not shout. Anyway, the clause “if the LMFDB chose [the uniform normalization]” is counterfactual hence meaningless. What I think you mean, and should write, is: (say, for odd analytic rank) let $Z(t)=i(2\pi)^{-it}\frac{\Gamma(1+it)}{|\Gamma(1+it)|}L(E,1+it)$, then does one have, for small $t>0$, $Z(t)>0$ (the curve starts off in the “first quadrant”, if I understand you correctly), or $Z(t)<0$ (the curve starts off “in the fourth quadrant”), depending on the analytic rank $r$ of $E$? Do I understand correctly? If so, the initial sign of $Z(t)$ should be $(-1)^{(r+1)/2}$ under RH.

Note that the “rank 3” phenomenon which you claim is general does not occur for the elliptic curve 5077.a1, and the graphs of the Z-functions of the other rank-$3$ elliptic curves seem to contradict the stated normalization of the LMFDB. I have reported this and it was made into a ticket: https://github.com/LMFDB/lmfdb/issues/6131 .

Aphelli, your comments are correct and fantastic! Yes, I was incorrect / incomplete in my LMFDB "observational study". Have you roughly estimate what proportion of rank-3 elliptic curves are Z(t) < 0 "fourth quadrant" versus Z(t) > 0 "first quadrant"? Any defining "Invariants" parameter, etc between the two cases??? Thanks from John Ting

"Github" Denote r = Analytic rank. LMFDB normalization is different to "Sign normalization" for epsilon which is (1)^{r-1} for even r with epsilon = 1 and (i)^{r-1} for odd r with epsilon = i [that obeys root of unity (for i)]. Intuitively, one anticipate Sign changes to occur exactly when r = 1, 2 (mod 4) BUT: [I] For even r = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...; 1^{r-1} = (1)^{-1}, (1)^{1}, (1)^{3}, (1)^{5}, (1)^{7}... = same +1 sign [of +1, +1, +1, +1, +1,...]. c.f. [II] For odd r = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9...; i^{r-1} = (i)^{0}, (i)^{2}, (i)^{4}, (i)^{6}, (i)^{8}... = alternating +/- 1 sign [of +1, -1, +1, -1, +1,...].

Above excerpt was posted by me at https://github.com/LMFDB/lmfdb/issues/6131#issuecomment-2287393884 . I also opine whether Z(t) plot for elliptic curve 5077.a1 https://www.lmfdb.org/L/2/5077/1.1/c1/0/410 could somehow be "incorrectly" plotted OR is a "rare" exception. Kind regards, John Ting
